# Запрос на сортировку

Tags: mysqli

Есть две таблицы, первая:

```
create table task_type
(
    id   int auto_increment
        primary key,
    name text          null,
    type text          null,
    obc  int default 0 null,
    sr   int default 0 null,
    osr  int default 0 null
);
```

вторая:

```
create table tasks
(
    id        int auto_increment,
    obc       int null,
    sr        int null,
    osr       int null,
    task_type text          null,
    constraint tasks_id_uindex
        unique (id)
);
```

Таблица tasks связана с таблицей task_type, ее id.

Задача заключается в следующем: как сделать такой запрос, что бы из таблицы tasks выводились в определенном порядке строки с одинаковыми типами.

К примеру в столбце type таблицы task_type лежат следующие строки: 1)обычная, 2)срочная, 3)очень срочная, 4)очень срочная, 5)обычная, 6)обычная. А запрос из таблицы tasks должен получать соответствующие строки в таком порядке: 3)очень срочная, 4)очень срочная, 2) срочная, 1)обычная, 5) обычная, 6) обычная.

Comment: Field_in_set только медленнл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`` ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(`код типа`, '3,4,2,1,5,6') ``

Но правильнее - добавить в таблицу типов поле приоритета при сортировке.

Comment: А если порядок произвольный ?

Comment: @ДмитрийБелый Зададите одинаковое значение поля приоритета. Пусть работает "рандом".

Comment: `ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(type, 'очень срочная,срочная,обычная')`.